# kendo.data.js and kendo.core.js have eslint no-new-func error

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, eslint

kendo.data.js and kendo.core.js use Function() constructor. These results in eslint no-new-func errors. The function body for the Function constructors is derived from multiple lines as well. How to avoid this issue?